# Implement Multiplicative Fuzzy Logic

Tags: code-golf, math, interpreter

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59299/43319) excellent challenge (from which the bulk of this text is blatantly duct-taped) – and my highschool philosophy [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Define_with_multiply)...

I define the following operators:

**Fuzzy Conjunction** *a* ×<sub>F</sub> *b* is *a* × *b*

**Fuzzy Division** *a* ÷<sub>F</sub> *b* is *a* ÷ *b*

**Fuzzy Negation** –<sub>F</sub> *b* is 1 – *b*

**Fuzzy Disjunction** *a* +<sub>F</sub> *b* is –<sub>F</sub> ((–<sub>F</sub> *a*) ×<sub>S</sub> (–<sub>F</sub> *b*) which is equivalent to 1 – (1 – *a*) × (1 – *b*)

With all this in mind, create an interpreter that will evaluate infix expressions that use the following operators (i.e., `a + b`, not `a b +` or `+ a b`). Alternatively, extend the language of your choice to include the notation.

```
×    Multiplication
÷    Division
–    Subtraction
+    Addition
×F   Fuzzy Conjunction
÷F   Fuzzy Division
–F   Fuzzy Negation
+F   Fuzzy Disjunction
```

Notice that *a* -<sub>F</sub> *b* is **not** defined. You may leave it undefined, or define it as you see fit.

You may substitute `*` for `×` and/or `-` for `–` and/or `/` for `÷`, (or use whatever single symbols your language uses for the four basic arithmetic operations) as long as you stay consistent: You may not use `*` and `×F` together.

You may choose to require or prohibit spacing around tokens.

You may choose any of the following rules for order of precedence:

1. As normal mathematics, and *each* Fuzzy operator has a *higher* order precedence than their normal counterpart.
2. As normal mathematics, and *each* Fuzzy operator has a *lower* order precedence than their normal counterpart.
3. As normal mathematics, and the Fuzzy operators *all* have *higher* order precedence than all the normal operators.
4. As normal mathematics, and the Fuzzy operators *all* have *lower* order precedence than all the normal operators.
5. Strict left-to-right.
6. Strict right-to-left.
7. Normal and *Fuzzy* operators have the *same* precedence and are evaluated left-to-right.
8. Normal and *Fuzzy* operators have the *same* precedence and are evaluated right-to-left.

Leave a comment if you desire another precedence rule.

Test cases using precedence rule 6:

```
> 5 +F 10 + 3
-47     // 1 - (1 - 5) × (1 - 13)
> 10 × 2
20      // 2 × 10
> 10 ×F 1
10      // 1 × 10
> 23 × 3
69      // 23 × 3
> 123 ×F 2 × 3
738     // 123 × 2 × 3
> 5 + 3 +F 2
4       // 5 + 1 - (1 - 3) × (1 - 2)
> 150 ÷F 3
50      // 150 ÷ 3
> 150 ÷ 53
2.83    // 150 ÷ 53
> -F -F -F 0
1       // 1 - (1 - (1 - 0))
> -500
-500    // - 500
> -F 6 - 1
-4      // 1 - 5
> 12 +F 633 ×F 3
-20877  // 1 - (1 - 12) × (1- 633 × 3)
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm trying this in Dyalog APL, and something feels *wrong* about using APL with regex.

Comment: Does `-M` nest arbitrarily? That is, should our code handle `-M -M -M 3` and the like?

Comment: Also, maybe allow `/` for `÷`?

Comment: Could the operators have the same precedence level as their normal counterparts?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes, you could translate Mauris' answer, but much more fun to define an APL operator to do the work.

Comment: @Mauris Yes. I had that in mind, but forgot to write it somehow. Fixed. Also, I messed up F/M. You may use either, but I've edited to F only. M is for Manhattan math!

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Yes, I'll add those to the list.

Comment: Can I define the monadic uses of +F, ×F, and ÷F along with the dyadic use of -F?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes, as long as the 8 required operations work, all other behaviour is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
⁾-Cyœṣ⁾+Fj“+_×ɗ”ḟ”FV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4z5d58qjkx/uXAxkartlPWqYox1/ePrJ6Y8a5j7cMR9IuoX9f7h7i/WjpjWPGrepHG4HMo5Oerhzxv//hgYK2grGCtpuCqZcQPbh6QpGENpNwZDLyBgkYMxlBKYggkbGXGDlRkB9QC2mQLXb3YBqICwFU2MuAwVdNwjiijc1MOAyU4hXMATxzIwhZoD1GxoBAA)

<s>To quote [myself](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56585104#56585104):</s>

> Well, it's disgustingly hacked together, but it works :D

Well, it's much more elegantly hacked together.

Haha, beating QuadR!

Jelly doesn't like strings. For a more elegant solution that exploits Jelly natural infix notation, see below. Takes input from ARGV. The Footer in the link takes a multiline string, splits it on newlines, runs each line and returns a list of results.

This uses precedence rule 5, which is consistent (I believe) with Jelly's parsing rules in this case, and we use `_` for regular subtraction and for regular negation.

### How it works

```
⁾-Cyœṣ⁾+Fj“+_×ɗ”ḟ”FV - Main link. Takes an expression E on the left
⁾-C                  - Yield ["-", "C"]
   y                 - Replace all occurrences of "-" with "C"
      ⁾+F            - Yield ["+", "F"]
    œṣ               - Split on "+F"
          “+_×ɗ”     - Yield "+_×ɗ"
         j           - Join on "+_×ɗ"
                ḟ”F  - Remove any leftover "F"s
                   V - Execute as Jelly code
```

#### Why `C` and `+_×ɗ`?

First, `C`. `C` is Jelly's builtin for \$1 - x\$

Now, `+_×ɗ`. The `ɗ` at the end tells Jelly to consider the previous 3 atoms as a single link, acting similarly to `(...)` in other languages. The three atoms implement the formula

$$\begin{align}
1 - (1-a)(1-b) & = 1 - (1-a-b+ab) \\
& = (a+b)-(a\times b)
\end{align}$$

```
+_× - Takes a on the left and b on the right
+   - a+b
  × - a×b
_   - a+b - a×b
```

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 + 8 = 17 bytes

```
×
÷
C
+_×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdK7D27mcubTjD0//b6xgcrRBwUhBW8H0PwA) or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9DcJQDIR7T3F9hOSfvAeIkkFS0aAsQMcWGYAhUiLxYK4XxxaF7/Od7Lvf5vnR20JtpSsNU1u6MAYYxt8Thdy0BbpTPBBS2wMjDWSoRnmv/uk/haHuLLa2ohgx7Pv@Dx0KM1VMkLDVsihLRHv5vHBBDT2GnkLPocIJSWjCEmMiG8Qr@gY)

Slightly convoluted here, but bear with me. This uses the

> Alternatively, extend the language of your choice to include the notation.

rule to avoid any parsing or complicated stuff that Jelly isn't too good at. Instead we define 4 functions `1ŀ`, `2ŀ`, `3Ŀ` and `4ŀ` (Conjuction, Division, Negation and Disjuction respecitively), which "extends" Jelly to include the fuzzy operations by including the above 9 bytes before any code. I'm counting my byte count here as 9 bytes for the code above plus 8 bytes for the names of the functions.

This uses precedence rule 5, which is consistent (I believe) with Jelly's parsing rules in this case, and we use `_` for regular subtraction.

In the test suite above, we include our 4 functions in the header, then execute the lines of test cases with the Footer.

### How it works

The names of the functions are fairly easy to understand. Jelly allows you to call each line as a function using the `Ŀ` (call as monad) or the `ŀ` (call as dyad) quicks, which is what we use here.

`1ŀ` and `2ŀ` are obvious how they work. `3Ŀ` simply takes advantage of Jelly's builtin for \$1 - x\$: `C`. `4ŀ` works the same way as specified above, but doesn't need the `ɗ` for grouping

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 45 bytes

```
q"-F"/"1 -"*"+F"/"1Y$-*+"*'F-S/)d\2/'\f*W%S*~
```

Uses precedence rule 6: strictly right-to-left. It expects ASCII input.

[Take it for a spin!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22-F%22%2F%221%20-%22*%22%2BF%22%2F%221Y%24-*%2B%22*'F-S%2F)d%5C2%2F'%5Cf*W%25S*~&input=12%20%2BF%20633%20*F%203)

### Explanation

Read input, and perform the following transformations in order:

```
"-F"   to   "1 -"
"+F"   to   "1Y$-*+"
 "F"   to   ""
```

Then split over spaces (`S/`). Extract the rightmost element and convert it to a double (`)d`). Then take pairs from the rest of the list (`\2/`), join them all by `\` (`'\f*`) and evaluate the resulting strings as CJam code in reverse order (`W%S*~`).

For example, it converts `5 +F 10 + 3`

- to `5 1Y$-*+ 10 + 3` in the first step,
- then to `3 [["10" "+"] ["5" "1Y$-*+"]]`,
- then to `3 ["10\+" "5\1Y$-*+"]`,
- then to `3 10\+ 5\1Y$-*+`, which is CJam code that computes the right answer, `-47`.

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 21 bytes

```apl
⍎⍵
\+F
-F
F
(+-×)
1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6//9Rb9@j3q1cMdpuXLpuXG5cGtq6h6drchnqcv3/b6qg7aZgaKCgrWCs8Ki7BcQ8PF3BCMEGyoI5pmAlQMVQOVOg5HY3mC4jkIyZsTFYgzEA) [or a version that accepts newline-separated test cases.](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6//9Rb9@j3iWGj/qmuvmGPOrdyhWj7cal68blxqWhrXt4uiaXoS7X//@mCtpuCoYGCtoKxlxA6vB0BSMIDRTlMgUJgxQAxUyBgtvdQKqMQCJmxsZgRcYA)

QuadR port of [Razetime's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216446/78410), as it happens to be a set of `⎕R` substitution followed by post-processing code. I moved `⍵~'F'` part into the regex substitution `'F' → ''`, which saves a byte. It has no problem running multiple test cases separated by `⋄`, but it does have some problem with newlines (which can be fixed by changing the first line to `⍎⍤1⎕FMT⍵`).

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>38 37 35</s></sup> 30 bytes

```apl
⍎'F'~⍨'\+F' '-F'⎕R'(+-×)' '1-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZG/SgNBEMb7PMV0m@Nc2T/Zu7MWFm0TS5uAxCagrY2NkEK4oIWksrcQbAR78yb7IufMzu5e4nEsw@xvvplvdnm/ljcPy/Xd7TCEfiu8eAz9h7iuvQAhvQjbt7mY1nK/qzChpRhWYfOCZHh@Cv1n6L9/v2zYvCK3mJ/jeXVxuRhWIBzUHrSCGqyASejfQc5aoO8ENEiY0uEq2O841LaaYBlWYMakEqMglRhKa1UQ1E6MLoweGWMpzp2bsyLD@SgTY8/KmWxtl8UYNYV3ZIVM5eFmkFXpqniyoyfDlhwO/ONLDzcOHG/SOBy7TJnTzh5RLmLSA/8q2wf4v9V4qCo2l05lkkImcfFKJbWGdl9e6FDL8ZbIcmN5V@Upjera9qipNsm3TDQu4g8)

A tacit function which accepts a string.

Evaluation is done as per Rule 6: strict right to left, as per APL's evaluation.

-1 byte from Adám.

-2 more from Adám.

-5 bytes from Bubbler.

### Explanation

```apl
⍎'F'~⍨'\+F' '-F'⎕R'(+-×)' '1-'
            '-F'⎕R        '1-'  regex replace '-F' with '1-'
      '\+F'     ⎕R'(+-×)'       regex replace '+F' with function to perform 1-((1-x)×(1-y))
 'F'~⍨                          remove any other Fs
⍎                               execute as APL code
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you.

Comment: I saw this challenge and *knew* you had to have already implemented it.

Comment: Do you know `⎕R` can take multiple regexes and transformation patterns at once?

Comment: @Adám forgot about that, -1

Comment: But now you can make the whole thing a tacit function: `⍎r ⎕R t`

Comment: A bit of math: `{1-×/1-⍺⍵}` → `(+-×)` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##XZG/SgNBEMb7PMV0m@Nc2T/Zu7MWFm0TS5uAxCagrY2NkEK4oIWksrcQbAR78yb7IufMzu5e4nEsw@xvvplvdnm/ljcPy/Xd7TCEfiu8eAz9h7iuvQAhvQjbt7mY1nK/qzChpRhWYfOCZHh@Cv1n6L9/v2zYvCK3mJ/jeXVxuRhWIBzUHrSCGqyASejfQc5aoO8ENEiY0uEq2O841LaaYBlWYMakEqMglRhKa1UQ1E6MLoweGWMpzp2bsyLD@SgTY8/KmWxtl8UYNYV3ZIVM5eFmkFXpqniyoyfDlhwO/ONLDzcOHG/SOBy7TJnTzh5RLmLSA/8q2wf4v9V4qCo2l05lkkImcfFKJbWGdl9e6FDL8ZbIcmN5V@Upjera9qipNsm3TDQu4g8))

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)!

```apl
F←{⍺←1⋄⍺(×-⍣(2=⍺⍺2)⍺⍺)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/92AZPWj3l1AyvBRdwuQpXF4uu6j3sUaRrYg4d5dRpoQGkhtrf3/31RB203B0EBBW8GYS9dNAYIMuIAih6cDJbgMTYGs7W4KxgA)

Extends the language with a monadic operator `F`. Uses rule 6 (strict right-to-left). This fixes the [issues](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@1R24TqR727gJTBo@4WDUPdR71bNTVAIlAE4Wkcnq6rrQniRRtBZAxja///NzRQODzdTcGQy9AUyNrupmAMAA) Adám pointed out in the original answer.

`⍺⍺` is the input function (`+`, `-`, `×`, or `÷`), `⍺` is the left argument (`⍺←1` gives it a default value of `1`), and `⍵` is the right argument. `×-⍣(2=⍺⍺2)⍺⍺`, which Adám came up with, is applied to `⍺` and `⍵`. It's equivalent to `(⍺×⍵) -⍣(2=⍺⍺2) (⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵)`. If `⍺⍺` is `+`, then `2=⍺⍺2` (`2 = +2`) is true. If so, `⍣` subtracts its right argument `⍺+⍵` from its left argument `⍺×⍵` (this is equivalent to `1-(1-⍺)×(1-⍵)`. Otherwise, we just return what's on the right side. If it's multiplication or division, it's the same as normal `×` or `÷`. If it's fuzzy negation, then `⍺` is 1, so it'll be `1-⍵`.

Comment: [Issues](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@1R24TqR727gJTBo@4WDUPdR71bNTVAIlAE4Wkcnq6rrQniRRtBZAxja///NzRQODzdTcGQy9AUyNrupmAMAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: [`F←{⍺←1⋄⍺(×-⍣(2=⍺⍺2)⍺⍺)⍵}`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/92AZPWj3l1AyvBRdwuQpXF4uu6j3sUaRrYg4d5dRpoQGkhtrf3/31RB203B0EBBW8GYS9dNAYIMuIAih6cDJbgMTYGs7W4KxgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: It is simply applying `-` 0 or 1 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117885/discussion-between-adam-and-user).

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 106 bytes

```
type f=float
func`*~`(a,b:f):f=a*b
func`/~`(a,b:f):f=a/b
func`-~`(b:f):f=1-b
func`+~`(a,b:f):f=1- -~a* -~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vco7DoMwEIThnlNMadaxkL1KCiTugo1YBYlAClKk8dUdHhYizRTf/NPwSmn5vntII@Psl0I@U9dSbJW/hVrKWhpP4dDqT6usZtVs1mTT19IamOhpnZD67jnjDg3F0BGuLHaxjkERyoHAp23Fg/eH0w8)

Adds the four operators to Nim. Since operator names can't contain letters, it uses a tilde `~` instead, which I consider a very fuzzy character. Precedence is the same as the corresponding normal operators.